# I defeated the Wall of Flesh but hardmode wasn't activated

Tags: terraria-mobile

I killed the Wall of Flesh, he dropped the Breaker Blade and the Sorcerer Emblem but didn't drop the Pwnhammer and I'm still in normal mode, not in HARDMODE. Can anyone help me and what can I do?

Comment: Perhaps a bug. Have you tried killing him again?

Comment: Did it mention something about the spirits of light and dark having awakened? Since that would be the start of hardmode.

Comment: yes i killed him 3 more times. but in my world there are no more voodoo demons so i had to create new world and i got 3 more dolls there. i killed one wall of flesh(only after killing all of bosses) in new world but nothing happened in that world too.

Comment: @Arperum no. it only says wall of flesh defeated and makes cube made by Ebonstones(i think so) and drops inside.

Comment: @iMAGEbox I remember in one of my worlds that it took a while for Hardmode to load. How long are you waiting at the moment?

Comment: @VascovdEng i played more 12 hours(real time) after killing him. i defeated 1st wall of flash 2 days ago. and i killed him second after 6 hours.

Comment: Did you get a message saying "The ancient spirits of light and dark have been released."?

Comment: @3ventic no. it only says Wall Of Flesh defeated

Comment: @iMAGEbox do you play it on your mobile phone?

Comment: @VascovdEng yes.on ipad and on iphone too

Comment: @iMAGEbox I never heard of any limit to how many voodoo demons can spawn per world.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the [wikia](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall_of_Flesh#Notes) about the Wall of Flesh it states:

> On the mobile version, killing the Wall of Flesh does not start hard mode.

Comment: so how can i start hardmode?

Comment: Buy Terraria for $10,- on Steam. Or wait for the upcoming christmas/winter sale.

Comment: any possibility on mobile version?

Comment: No. There is not a possibility for it on the mobile version.